# Non-Audio Microphone

Tags: acoustics

Sound is simply vibrations travelling through the air. Would it be theoretically possible to *listen* to sounds through some other mechanism like infra-red or some fancy form of imaging?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and this is exactly what a [laser microphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_microphone) does. The vibrations caused by sound are converted into an oscillating light intensity.

This still relies on the sound waves causing a solid object to vibrate, so arguably the vibrating glass detected by the laser is just a proxy for our eardrums. In principle the changes in the refractive index of the air caused by compression (i.e. sound) waves could be detected directly, for example using an [etalon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabry%E2%80%93P%C3%A9rot_interferometer). Given how sensitive the etalons used at LIGO are I'm sure they would detect sound waves passing through them (LIGO uses a vacuum in its detectors for exactly this reason).

I don't know if anyone has built a system for doing this - it's not obvious there is much point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the signal is converted to mechanical vibrations before it reaches the ears (externally, or via other body parts like bones)